# WebSockets do not work on cellular network

Tags: android, websocket, cellular-network

I'm building an Android app as a WebSocket client, in particular using the com.neovisionaries.ws.client implementation.
This is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/).

The server is a NodeJS websocket server which relies on an HTTP server.
Now, everything is fine when connecting with WiFi, but I can't establish any connection over cellular network. I NEED the app could work also on cellular network. It seems that handshake fails at all. I hope nothing is wrong with the websocket library; maybe it could be due to the mobile provider. Any idea about this?

Comment: Just one possibility: There may be a proxy that does not support WebSocket in the network between your application and your server. If you are using 'ws:', try 'wss:'.